# Flutter; get index number for a list

Tags: list, android-studio, flutter, indexing

In my app, I have a list of 'goals'.

On the main page, there is a `list.map` than makes a button for each goal.

These buttons contain the name and description of the goal.

When the user clicks on them, they're taken to another page (`goalPage`)

When the goalPage loades, it needs to display the goal the user clicked on. I was thinking that if i could get acces to the list-idex-number of the goal, in the goalPage, it would work, because all the info I need is in the list. But I don't now how to get that index-number, spesially because it can change, it the user deletes a goal or adds a new one.

---

---

List *(on MainPage)*:

```
List<Goal> goals = [
   Goal(title: 'Example goal', description: 'this is an example goal'),
];
```

Display of goals *(on MainPage)*:

```
Column(
   children: goals.map((goal) => GoalTemplate(goal: goal)).toList(),
),
```

goal button template *(on goalTemplate file)*:

```
class GoalTemplate extends StatefulWidget {

  final Goal goal;
  GoalTemplate({this.goal});

  @override
  _GoalTemplateState createState() => _GoalTemplateState();
}

class _GoalTemplateState extends State<GoalTemplate> {

  int listIndex;

  void navToGoalPage () async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => GoalPage(),));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          listIndex = goals.indexOf();
        });
        navToGoalPage();
      },
      child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(widget.goal.title),
                Text(widget.goal.description),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

(The goal page doesn't work at all, well that's kinda why im asking here, I need to have a page, just with a Varioble of the current-index-value (**not** the total number of items in the list))

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from using map to using for function:

```
Column(
  children: [
    for(int index = 0; index < goals.length; index++) // goals[index] is what you want to get
      GoalTemplate(goal: goal)
  ]
)
```